# How to reduce the image size by reducing the quality when uploading images in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a Larvel website for ads, now users can upload very large images, I would like to resize, compress, reduce the quality of these images before storing them in the DB.

I have

```
$img = request->file("images");
```

Where do I go from here?

It seems strange to me how Php actually works. I was expecting some kind of byte[] array-like in Java that represents the image then do some calculation over it and we are done.

I checked a couple of posts like [this](https://makitweb.com/how-to-compress-image-size-while-uploading-with-php/#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20compressImage()%20function,%2C%20PNG%2C%20and%20GIF%20images.&text=Call%20imagecreatefromjpeg(%24source)%20%2C%20imagecreatefromgif,store%20image%20to%20the%20destination.) and this [one here](https://write.corbpie.com/compress-image-if-certain-size-in-php/)

However, all code snippets deal with local disk images is there a way I can use:

```
$img = request->file("images");
```

Or I don't understand how files work in PHP?

Comment: You can use https://image.intervention.io/v2 package to resize the images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spatie package or any other package for image manipulation:

[spatie image](https://github.com/spatie/image) with this package you can simply make:

```
Image::load($request->file("images")) // or its path
   ->width(100)
   ->height(100)
   ->save($pathToNewImage);
```

It also support for reducing image sizes by decreasing quality.